# How to find out the location of a failed assert? (Calling debug-build DLL in Unity)

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, vector, assert

Writing a C++ DLL to use from Unity3D.
If I build the DLL as release, I currently get some undefined behavior nonsense. If building as debug build, the following popup shows:

[image]

Unfortunately the error redirects into the vector class and not the place where it is actually used in my own code.
I know what DLL function causes this, but I cannot find out why this happens because there is a lot of vector handling. I do suspect some multithreading issue.

However how do I find out which particular line, aka which assert failed?
I do not seem to be able to catch asserts with the try-catch block.

Huge thanks in advance :)

Comment: Click retry, look at the call stack to find your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a stack trace when C++ program crashes? (using msvc8/2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112831/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-when-c-program-crashes-using-msvc8-2005) (It might be out of date, though.) *(Note that the linked answer was easier to find because it gave the error message as text instead of solely relying on an image -- hint, hint.)*

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the answer but unfortunately nothing happens if clicking Retry except that Unity crashes.

Comment: @JaMiT Fear that does not help directly. The thing is my exe is the Unity program which consists of a C# interpreter etc. The faulty code is a C++ Dll that is merely attached to Unity.

Comment: @DragonGamer Leave the assert box open. (a) If it happens on your dev machine, attach a debugger to the process that popped the assertion, then you'll have access to all symbols, the call stack etc. (b) Otherwise save a crash dump file, copy it to your machine, load it into a debugger and see (a).

Comment: Well if the debugger doesn't work there's always the alternative of not accessing the vector out of bounds.

Comment: The try-catch behavior is expected, as try-catch handles exceptions, but a failed assertion is program termination, not an exception. If you want to go the exception route, [`vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) should throw an exception when [`vector:operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) gives undefined behavior/debug assert. You said you know which function to look at, so temporarily changing that function might be not too onerous?

Comment: Another approach, somewhat crude but effective, is to log a diagnostic message to `std::cerr` after every line in the suspect function. (Use the unbuffered `cerr` for this, not the buffered `cout`.) If you can find where `cerr` data is sent, this should tell you which line to look at and potentially why you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to debug the Unity editor as a whole with attached DLLs.

1. Find out where the actual editor is (in the rightclick menu of the installs tab in  Unity Hub)
2. Open that EXE with Visual Studio (literally the "Open project" selection)
3. Go to the solutions properties -> parameters and add:
   -projectPath "PATH_TO_YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
4. Debug -> Start Debugging (or F5)
5. If you get an assertion etc. click "Retry".

Step 3 is important because for whatever reason, Unity does not show the "open a project" option if started as debug and just closes itself instead. That's what made me think that external debugging is not supported.